# Firebase hosting do not rewrite and go on index

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I created a website in Flutter and I got only two pages in my website. A HomePage and a DetailPage.

Currently, the HomePage is working well with the rule :

```
{
      "source": "/**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
}
```

I want to have the DetailPage working with the URL /item/:idItem

The problem is if I do something dumb like that :

```
{
      "source": "/item/:idItem",
      "destination": "/item/:idItem"
}
```

I'm on a 404 Page Not Found from Firebase. I need to point on the HomePage, with the custom URL because it's my HomePage that is retrieving URL and choosing if I show the Home or the Details.

Comment: The syntax looks unfamiliar. Usually, it is done like described here https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes

Comment: It's the syntax for the firebase.json file. Because it's the firebase I am trying to configure. The website in local works fine.

Comment: In case it works fine locally, there is no need to change `source` and `destination` in firebase.json as the routing is internally solved by Flutter. It seems, the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: If you reset the firebase.json to the one version created by flutterfire / firebase and then do a `firebase deploy`, what is the error scenario? There are 2 or 3 common know scenarios where something does not work. But to understand you case, it would be helpful to have more information about the initial error.